# Create file google drive API in php

Tags: php, google-drive-api

i want create file in my drive and i follow this link https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation. Now i create my file and directory but files and directory don't appear in my Drive.

If i list my drive, i can see all created files and directories in the var_dump but i don't see the existing files in my real drive.

Do you have a solution ?

```
  function retrieveAllFiles($service) {

    $result = array();
      $pageToken = NULL;

      do {
        try {
          $parameters = array();
          if ($pageToken) {
            $par

ameters['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
      }
      $files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);

      $result = array_merge($result, $files->getItems());
      $pageToken = $files->getNextPageToken();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
      $pageToken = NULL;
    }
  } while ($pageToken);
  var_dump($result);
  return $result;
}
```

Comment: i can see the owner is always empty. How can i do to full the owner ?

Comment: i find the solution with  
$auth->prn = 'mailuser';

Answer (score 0):

Please use:

```
$auth->prn = 'mailuser';
```

to complete the delegation.